# Sending objects between GDScript and Rust using TCP

Tags: json, rust, godot, gdscript

I want to connect my game to a rust server and have an event based communication.

The enum on the rust side looks somewhat like this:

```rs
enum Event {
    Login(String),
    LoadChunk(Chunk),
    ChunkUpdate(Chunk),
}
```

I already got a very simple Client and Server using `StreamPeerTCP` and `std::net::TcpListener` working and I can already send utf8 encoded strings between them.

Now I want to send an event from the server to the client.
To do so I serialize the event on the server into JSON and then send the bytes from this string to the client using `as_bytes()`.

This is the function on the client which processes the data received from `StreamPeerTCP`:

```
func _handle_client_data(data: PoolByteArray) -> void:
    var string_data: String = data.get_string_from_utf8();

    var parsed_data: Object = JSON.parse(string_data);
```

But now due to loose typing I do not know how I should access any fields from the object.

I think I am doing something fundamentally wrong but I do not know any better solution.

Can anyone help me on how to approach such a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I moved the whole TCP-client to rust and tokio using GDNative.

The interface between the rust and GDscript languages is still JSON.

the client emits a `Event` signal which gets handled in this function by the `TcpClientWrapper`:

```
func handle_event(event: String):
    var type: String = event.split('"', true, 2)[1];
    match type:
        "Error":
            var kind: String = JSON.parse(event).result.Error;
            self.emit_signal("Error", kind);
        "Token":
            var token: Array = JSON.parse(event).result.Token;
            self.emit_signal("Token", token);
        _:
            # ChunkUpdate not yet implemented
            print("invalid event type");
```

The original Event in rust:

```rs
pub enum ServerToClient {
    Error(ClientError),
    Token(Token),
    ChunkUpdate(Chunk),
}
```

To interface With the client I have this script in `ClientTcpWrapper`:

```
extends Node;

# position and string
signal ChunkUpdate(position, chunk);
# array
signal Token(token);
# string
signal Error(kind);

export var host: String = "0.0.0.0:8000";

onready var client: Node = self.get_node("TcpClient");

func _ready():
    client.establish_connection(host);
    
    client.connect("Event", self, "handle_event");
    
func connection_established() -> bool:
    return client.connection_established();
    
func register(name: String):
    var string = '{"Register":{"name":"' + name + '"}}';
    client.send(string);

func move(pos: Vector3):
    var x = str(pos.x).pad_decimals(10);
    var y = str(pos.y).pad_decimals(10);
    var z = str(pos.z).pad_decimals(10);
    var string = '{"Move":{"coord":[' + x + "," + y + "," + z + ']}}';
    
    client.send(string);
    
func handle_event(event: String):
    var type: String = event.split('"', true, 2)[1];
    match type:
        "Error":
            var kind: String = JSON.parse(event).result.Error;
            self.emit_signal("Error", kind);
        "Token":
            var token: Array = JSON.parse(event).result.Token;
            self.emit_signal("Token", token);
        _:
            print("invalid event type");
```